# Why would this Core 1 web app render no output?

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I've just started following a tutorial, and not even the evergreen "Hello world" works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This is in `wwwroot` and any other code in the project is VS generated boilerplate. I would expect to see a `Hello` header on my page when I run the project, but there is nothing visible, even if I view page source the page is completely snow white.

Comment: What does your `Startup.cs` look like? Is this just an `index.html`? Are you using MVC? Do you have controller routes hooked up? Are you using [default files?](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html#serving-a-default-document)

Comment: And we have a winner! It was the static files. I am a rank beginner with Core, and always just copy and paste those services in. Of course I'd forget when I'm sort of doing the code myself. I'll accept your's as soon as I can.

Comment: did the answer below solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want ASP to serve up an index.html file you'll need to enable it by adding `UseDefaultFiles()` and `UseStaticFiles()` in your `Startup.cs` `Configure()` method.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html#serving-a-default-document